# Adding degrees to complex numbers

Tags: complex

I'd like to take the complex number $(1 + 0i)$ and (i) multiply it by $0.5$ and (ii) add 45 degrees to it (without changing its magnitude). But I'd like to get its complex represenation in non-polar coordinates (i.e., some $(x +yi)$).

How do I do compute like this in Mathematica?

Comment: I'm familiar with the basics of Mathematica but have never used it to manipulate complex numbers before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding 45 degrees do you mean rotating by 45 degrees?

Let's do this symbolically first. Multiply a complex number `x + I y` by a scalar `a` and then rotate by   θ.

```
e1 = a (x + I y) E^(I θ)
```

> `a E^(I θ) (x + I y)`

Then to get this into the x + I y form you do

```
ComplexExpand[e1]
```

> a x Cos[θ] - a y Sin[θ] + I (a y Cos[θ] + a x Sin[θ])

In the numerical case this is just

```
1 0.5 E^(I π/4)
```

> 0.353553 + 0.353553 I

Comment: Or using exact numbers `1/2*Exp[I*45*Degree] // ComplexExpand`